# Are for loop conditions optimised?

Tags: javascript, optimization, compiler-construction, for-loop

A few years ago I heard that the condition part of a for loop is evaluated every time the loop runs. Also, that property access is relatively expensive.

Since then I've had the habit of writing for loops as:

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
for (var i=0, l=data.length; i<l; i++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Is this an unneeded optimisation? Do modern Javascript compilers/interpreters already optimise the condition part so the length property isn't accessed multiple times?

How much of an effect does this have anyway?

Comment: I don't think optimizers do that... If the loop is big then cache it otherwise the performance difference is trivial.

Comment: To sum up: the programmer should do this in case the optimizer doesn't do it, but the optimizer should do it as well in case the programmer doesn't do it.

Comment: "*relatively* expensive" -- indeed, but in 99.99999% of cases, neither case would be noticably faster

Comment: @H2CO3 I disagree. The amount of times I have run into loops that need to be so micro-optimized can be counted on about .. 2 fingers. One was for a "game of life" state check; I can't recall the other.

Comment: I often do `for (var i=data.length; i--;)`, and that's always seemed faster to me with many iterations as it skips the operator, but it does do it in reverse order of course, if that's important? On the other hand I know nothing about how the JS engine actually work!

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered very well unless it's targeted at a specific JS engine and a version thereof.

Comment: @pst you can agree and disagree to whatever you want, this is my opinion, and at least the JavaScript engine should optimize this anyway (why do you think certain low-quality engines run code *hundreds* of times slower than others?)

Comment: @H2CO3 I was specifically referring to "the programmer should do this" - which I am opposed to 97% of the time, per the 97/3 rule. (But yes, I hope that modern engines are efficiently optimized within the bounds of the language semantics.)

Answer (score 3):

> Is this an unneeded optimisation?

Yes, it almost always is. I'm sure every single JavaScript implementation has `O(1)` complexity to get the length. The only case I can imagine where you really want to use even the tiniest optimization is a game engine. But if you write a "normal" JavaScript application it really won't matter - and without that optimization your code is much nicer to read.

You also need to see that possible bit of performance loss in contrast to the body of your loop. It most likely involves accessing other variables, properties of the element you are iterating over, or even modify the DOM (which is usually expensive like hell).

If loop performance was a huge issue in most cases you can be pretty sure that vendors wouldn't have implemented `Array.prototype.forEach()` which comes with the overhead of a function call for every "iteration" - compared to DOM manipulations (which are especially likely in case jQuery's `.each()` is used) even that is cheap.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what ThiefMaster said, it's common to iterate over arrays with something like:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.forEach(function(el, i) {
   //...
});
```

or

```
$.each(arr, function(i, el){
   //...
});
```

If invoking a *whole function* for each iteration is usually acceptable, then checking the length of an array almost certainly will be.

Comment: Just because there is a different way to do it doesn't justify (one way or the other) whether one needs to do an optimization or not.

Comment: You're right, @Matt - I was addressing the `How much of an effect does this have anyway?` part of his question.

Comment: But just because something is "common" isn't an argument.  I've seen plenty of code that is "commonly" acceptable, but falls apart under a certain use case.  When talking about optimizations, the only thing that matters is the empirical evidence of your actual scenario, and what your profiler tells you.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a

In mozilla:

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) //4ms
for (var i=0, len=arr.length; i<len; i++) //3ms
```

I think this is a lycorn problem.

Comment: That benchmark would be flagged as VLQ if it was on a SO-like site. 4ms vs 3ms - in case of such minor differences microsecond accuracy would be appropriate.

Comment: 1000 entries according to that site. So way too small IMO

Answer (score 0):

This particular case is so common that it is safe to assume it is optimized.  For example, in Java, that for loop is listed in their documentation as the only case where they will optimize away bounds checks (an expensive thing to do in java).

I recommend looking at it the other way:  If this, the most common case imaginable, is not optimized, then it is highly likely that there are many other cases where your particular engine doesn't optimize... so many that the idea of manually optimizing seems a bit ludicrous.